# SendGrid Marketing Email Delay?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sendgrid

**Steps**

1. Create recipient list
2. Create marketing Email
3. Add emails to recipient list
4. Assign recipient list to marketing email

When I debug slowly, i managed to passed all steps with success message from sendgrid.

But in non debug mode, although i added emails to recipient list success(results return from sendgrid), when in step 4, i get results return **List without recipients**. I refresh the browser and saw the emails in the recipient list as well.

I tried to put timer.interval before start to process step 4 but also get the same results return.

**VB ProcessHandler Code**

```
' Add email and name to recipient list 
 If oSendMarketingEmail.AddEmailToList(oItemDetails.Email, oItemDetails.Full_Name, sRecipientList) = False Then Exit Try

' Wait for the email and name added to recipient list
 Dim timer As New Timers.Timer
 timer.Interval = 20000

 ' Assigning recipient list to marketing email
  If oSendMarketingEmail.AddListToMarketingEmail(sMarketingEmailName, sRecipientList) = False Then Exit Try
```

**VB Function Code**

```
    Public Function AddEmailToList(sEmailAddress As String, sName As String, sRecipientList As String) As Boolean

        Dim ResultsHTML As String = ""

        Dim URL As String = (Convert.ToString("http://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.xml?list=") & sRecipientList) + "&data=" + "{""email"":""" + sEmailAddress + """,""name"":""" + sName + """}" + "&api_user=" + SendGridUserName + "&api_key=" + SendGridPassword
        Dim SendGridResponse As String = PerformHTTPGet(URL)
        ResultsHTML += (Convert.ToString("Adding email to List: ") & SendGridResponse) + "<br/>"

        ' Check respond status - success
        If Not ResultsHTML.Contains("insert") Then logger.log.Info(ResultsHTML) : Return False Else Return True

    End Function


    Public Function AddListToMarketingEmail(sMarketingEmailName As String, sRecipientList As String) As Boolean

        Dim ResultsHTML As String = ""

        'Assign list to marketing email
        Dim URL As String = (Convert.ToString((Convert.ToString("http://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/recipients/add.xml?name=") & sMarketingEmailName) + "&list=") & sRecipientList) + "&api_user=" + SendGridUserName + "&api_key=" + SendGridPassword
        Dim SendGridResponse As String = PerformHTTPGet(URL)
        ResultsHTML += (Convert.ToString("Assigning Marketing Email to List: ") & SendGridResponse) + "<br/>"

        ' Check respond status - success
        If Not ResultsHTML.Contains("success") Then logger.log.Info(ResultsHTML) : Return False

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SendGrid, the list-count can take a little while to update. One way to "force" it is to query the full list, which triggers the system to count through, and will update the count, which will then allow you to attach it properly.

Comment: Hi jacob, i found a way to solve this which is before adding the list to marketing email, i put a system.threading.thread.sleep(milliseconds). It works perfect now. Do you have any idea or is there any solutions to add in each recipient information to the marketing email without have to recreate them?

Comment: i found the way on how to add the recipient information into the marketing email. 

Another issue that I've encountered is that after I try to add category to a marketing email, i go to the UI to check whether the marketing email is in the category. The category isn't turn into bold. But when i create a marketing email and select the category, the category will turn into bold. Do you have any idea what might causes this?

Comment: CODE

' Add newsletter category to newsletter
            Dim URL As String = "https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/category/add.json" + "&api_user=" + SendGridUserName + "&api_key=" + SendGridPassword + "&category=Newsletters" + "&name=" + EncodedNewsletterName
            Dim SendGridResponse As String = PerformHTTPGet(URL)
            ResultsHTML += (Convert.ToString("Add Category to Newsletter: ") & SendGridResponse) + "<br/>"

            ' Check respond status - success
            If Not ResultsHTML.Contains("success") Then logger.log.Info(ResultsHTML) : Return False Else Return True

Comment: I had to put a waiting time (thread sleep 20 seconds average), and try 3 attempts to ensure that the marketing email will be sent

Comment: @tiveor have you tried the new Marketing Campaigns platform? It's a lot better than the Legacy Newsletter in a lot of ways.

Comment: @jacobmovingfwd yes, we have planned to move over there, I would really like the feature [weblink] are available on send email, that's is I was looking to create marketing email in the current implementation that we have